# QTreeView - remove expandable look on some elements

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I'd like to remove expandable attribute on some elements in QTreeView (populated with model inherited from QFileSystemModel). I can easily collapse this elements right after they are expanded, but they will be still visible in QTreeView as expandable.
How can I show them as unexpandable ones?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you just have to override the default behaviour in the `rowCount` of your `QFileSystemModel` derived class to return zero rows for when that `QModelIndex` of the row you don't want to be expandable.

See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/model-view-programming.html#models particularly the Tree Model diagram.